# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException - column cannot be null

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using JPA 2.1 in WildFly 8.0.1. The following line is throwing this exception:

```
configuration.setClient(client);
clientBean.edit(client);
```

In `Configuration` class, `Client` has `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}`. `Cliente` is related to some entities like `City`, `State`, etc. They also have `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}`.

Stack trace at http://pastebin.com/zR7mq87f

Comment: client is null. The exception is telling you it cannot be null.

Comment: It's selected in the view in a combo box and value is sent to the managed bean.

Answer (score 0):

bairro_id is null, and the column table probably has not null constrain

10:46:50,941 INFO  [stdout] (default task-61) Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'bairro_id' cannot be null

Comment: "SELECT bairro_id FROM cliente" does not return any NULL value

Comment: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)

                             
you execute an update :) and the client object that you are passing has id with value null, just do a debug and you'll see

Comment: I do `merge` in the entity to avoid `PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist`. And `Client` has an id, I debugged it.